# OpenNebula running a virtual machine fail

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, open-source

Hi I am trying run virtual machine with OpenNebula by this tutorial:
http://docs.opennebula.org/4.8/design_and_installation/quick_starts/qs_centos7_kvm.html

but when I want to instantiate a template, so vm fails and in log is:

```
Wed Nov 12 09:48:25 2014 [Z0][DiM][I]: New VM state is ACTIVE.
Wed Nov 12 09:48:25 2014 [Z0][LCM][I]: New VM state is PROLOG.
Wed Nov 12 09:48:25 2014 [Z0][TM][I]: Command execution fail: /var/lib/one/remotes/tm/shared/clone localhost.localdomain:/var/lib/one//datastores/1/ea53f24b6bd08f5a59d41f69fe4e356f localhost:/var/lib/one//datastores/0/9/disk.0 9 1
Wed Nov 12 09:48:25 2014 [Z0][TM][I]: clone: Cloning /var/lib/one/datastores/1/ea53f24b6bd08f5a59d41f69fe4e356f in localhost:/var/lib/one//datastores/0/9/disk.0
Wed Nov 12 09:48:25 2014 [Z0][TM][E]: clone: Command "cd /var/lib/one/datastores/0/9; cp /var/lib/one/datastores/1/ea53f24b6bd08f5a59d41f69fe4e356f /var/lib/one/datastores/0/9/disk.0" failed: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
Wed Nov 12 09:48:25 2014 [Z0][TM][E]: Error copying localhost.localdomain:/var/lib/one//datastores/1/ea53f24b6bd08f5a59d41f69fe4e356f to localhost:/var/lib/one//datastores/0/9/disk.0
Wed Nov 12 09:48:25 2014 [Z0][TM][I]: ExitCode: 255
Wed Nov 12 09:48:25 2014 [Z0][TM][E]: Error executing image transfer script: Error copying localhost.localdomain:/var/lib/one//datastores/1/ea53f24b6bd08f5a59d41f69fe4e356f to localhost:/var/lib/one//datastores/0/9/disk.0
Wed Nov 12 09:48:25 2014 [Z0][DiM][I]: New VM state is FAILED
```

Do you know what is wrong?
Thanks

Comment: So I solve it by execute sshd

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells that you can not connect to localhost using ssh:

```
failed: ssh: connect to host localhost port 22: Connection refused
```

Is sshd running and port 22 open in the firewall?